# Laravel array key exists in get method

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch the the id and the name of the categories which is related to my services. A service has many categories and a categories belongs to a services. However when I try to get the id and the name as an array to return it gives me this error.

> array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an
>   integer.

Here is my method or function.

```
public function getCategories($idService)
{
    $service = Service::findOrFail($idService);
    return $service->categories->get(['id','name']);;
}
```

and here is the defined route.

```
Route::get('service/{service}/categories', 'ServiceController@getCategories');
```

I tried to look and browse for it but can't find any solution at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ***pluck()*** method instead

```
return $service->categories->pluck('id','name');
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the parameter has to be equal to the wildcard and you need to use **pluck()** as mentioned in another comment, in your case:

```
public function getCategories($service)
{
    $service = Service::findOrFail($service);
    return $service->categories->pluck(['id','name']);
}
```

If service is a model you can also use eloquent:

```
public function getCategories(Service $service)
{
    return $service->categories->pluck(['id','name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess it related to `with` eager loading..need to use eager loading to fetch the relationship.. then use laravel collection if you want to filter more

```
public function getCategories($idService)
{
    return Service::with(['categories' => function ($query) {
         $query->select('id', 'name');
    }])->findOrFail($idService);
}
```